# Would the dispensation of Yefat Toar apply to homosexual men?

Tags: halacha-theory, sexuality, army-military-war, homosexuality

My understanding is that one of the reasons for the permissibility of a man to sleep with a woman who is part of an enemy nation during war is because the Torah is "speaking against the man's evil inclination". This is based on the understanding that they can actually engage in sexual relations on the battlefield.

I would like to understand if this same dispensation would in any way apply to male-only homosexual relations during war (either explicit relations or other sexual acts).

Comment: The pasuk says _*eshet* yefat to'ar_. The full explanation of the dispensation (see Sefer HaChinuch 532-534) is that it's permitted because the Torah disincentivises it in its conditions, which wouldn't apply to your case. Doing those things makes it permissible, but homosexual relations are never permissible

Comment: Your question is interesting, because we do put almost all other prohibitions regarding cohabitation aside for the Yefat Tohar (she's not Jewish, it doesn't matter whether or not she's married, the Gemarra even brings an opinion that a Kohain can marry her. But nonetheless, as @RabbiKaii points out, it's purely *eshet* Yefat toar (a woman and not a man) there is no dispensation for homosexuel relations